# Is it possible to invoke a virtualenv's python interpreter by including a line in the script?

Tags: python, virtualenv, shebang

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy with python. My setup is like so:

```
mkdir project
cd project
virtualenv project-env
project-env/bin/pip install SQLAlchemy
```

I activate the environment by navigating to the `bin` directory and using:

```
source activate
```

However I recently just followed some Flask tutorials (Flask also installed in a virtual env) and noticed that this step isn't required to run scripts correctly. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

In the python file from the tutorial (`run.py`) there is the line:

```
#!flask/bin/python
```

is this setting the path to the interpreter? I've tried:

```
#!project-env/bin/python
```

In my script and it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a terrible shebang line used in the tutorial; it's relative, which means it only works if you happen to be in a working directory that is directly outside the virtual environment.

That is, for that shebang to work, when the virtual env is in `~/foo/bar/project-env`, when you run the script, the only way it will work is if you've `cd`ed to `~/foo/bar`. Even if the script is in `~/foo/bar`, it won't work unless you `cd`ed there as well.

Use an absolute path, or use a canonical shebang line and actually activate the virtual environment first. I'd recommend the latter (I'm not fully confident that other tweaks made by the `activate` script aren't important in some cases), but the former will behave as the tutorial you linked expects.